# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I'm trying to create a web-app, in the security section I encountered this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.name()Ljava/lang/String;
```

here is applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <!--        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>-->
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <!--        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>-->
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>

        <!--        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test"/>-->
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="SASHAolic555"/>
        <!--        <property name="username" value="sa"/>-->
        <!--        <property name="password" value=""/>-->


    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <!--                                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>-->
                <!--                                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>-->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>


            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.emusicstore</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1024000"/>
    </bean>
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login
                login-page="/login"
                default-target-url="/admin/"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password" />
        <security:logout
                logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                        authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority FROM authorities WHERE username = ?"
                                        users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

this is  dispatcherServlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
</beans
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <absolute-ordering/>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mywebsite</groupId>
    <artifactId>emusicstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.name()Ljava/lang/String;
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
            at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4768)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1783)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
            at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
            at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
            at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:460)
            at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
            at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
            at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
            at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
            at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.name()Ljava/lang/String;
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:237)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:191)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:51)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$1.matches(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:175)
            at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector$1.doWith(HandlerMethodSelector.java:62)
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:496)
            at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector.selectMethods(HandlerMethodSelector.java:57)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:172)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:147)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:126)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
            ... 59 more
    27-Oct-2021 20:28:32.495 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    27-Oct-2021 20:28:32.496 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/eMusicStore] startup failed due to previous errors
    27-Oct-2021 20:28:32.514 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [eMusicStore] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
    [2021-10-27 08:28:32,525] Artifact eMusicStore:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
    27-Oct-2021 20:28:34.246 INFO [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1427)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1052)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:117)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:84)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    27-Oct-2021 20:28:35.295 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.52\webapps\manager]
    27-Oct-2021 20:28:35.517 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.52\webapps\manager] has finished in [220] ms
```

Comment: The `NoSuchMethodError` is generally thrown when you use different modules from spring with different versions, which seems to be the case here. Use something like maven or gradle to manage your dependencies and make sure the versions align. In this case it looks like you are trying to outsmart the Spring Boot starter projects (as you indicate you are using Spring Boot). Please add your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` to the question.

Comment: You should use a newer Spring Security version or an older Spring version. Spring Security 3.1 wasn't designed for Spring 4.1 (and in turn pulls in older versions of Spring libraries leading to this issue).

Answer (score -1):

You need to @Autowire SessionFactory where you are injecting. That's why IOC is not able to find the bean to instantiate the bean.

Comment: i did that before !!!

Comment: can you share your controller class

Comment: This isn't about not being able to find the session factory, it is about incompatible library versions.